# Notepad++ regex - how do I find a string and move it to the end of the line?

Tags: regex, notepad++

I've tried searching for this, but couldn't find one that worked for what I needed it for.

I'm trying to find [DLC] in a line, and move it to the end of that line.

Comment: Two groups should be fine. [Search for `(\[DLC\])(.*)` and replace with `$2$1`](https://regex101.com/r/2eJTkF/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this regex:

```
^(.*?)(\[DLC\])(.*)$
```

and replace with

```
$1$3$2
```

Explanation:

The regex splits the string into three groups:

1. everything before [DLC]
2. [DLC]
3. everything after [DLC]

and reorders the groups in the order of 1, 3, 2

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pMQyVh/1)

Comment: Notepad++ uses backslash for escaping group numbers.

Comment: @Sedo no I checked the wiki. $ is okay: http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Substitutions

Comment: @Sedo: It did, but it's very old, about 10 years ago!

Comment: Please explain why the `?` is needed there?

Comment: Without the question mark, group 2 will capture the last occurrence of [DLC], with it, the first occurrence will be captured. @sandthorn

Comment: May I say like `?` turns greed into ample greed?

Comment: @sandthorn it’s called lazy. see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2301285/5133585). Actually I was wrong. Without the ?, the regex will capture everything in the first group.

Comment: I guess not. Your first explaination is totally correct, without `?` , group 1 will be expanded, greedily, until the last occurance of [DLC].